Does all infinite sets are Dedekind infinite imply the union of a set of strictly smaller sets is subnumerous to it?
Working in $\sf ZF$ + every infinite set is Dedekind infinite.
Let $X$ be such that for each $y \in X$ we have $|y| < |X|$.

is it a theorem that  $|X \cup \bigcup X|=|X| $?

Note: The cardinality function $||$ here is defined after Scott's.

No, not at all. It is consistent that $\sf ZF+DC$ holds and there is a family of pairs of size $\aleph_1$ which doesn't admit a choice function.
But then the union of this family has size $\aleph_1$, and we can define the choice function using that.
